# WordPress - overwrite core function even after theme or site update

Tags: php, wordpress, function, upgrade, overwrite

I have googled this, of course, but I require a solution that stays put even after I upgrade a theme AND/OR upgrade the entire WordPress site to a newer version.

Basically, before a post is shown, I want to show specific HTML. And I want it absolutely foolproof because I will be handing over the site to an old guy. I also don't want any plugins installed because I am quite sure he will be clicking on stuff randomly. -it must be seamless.

It must be an analog of what this would do like this: (post-template.php)

```
function the_content( $more_link_text = null, $strip_teaser = false) {
$content = get_the_content( $more_link_text, $strip_teaser );

 /**
 * Filter the post content.
 *
 * @since 0.71
 *
 * @param string $content Content of the current post.
 */
$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
$content = str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;', $content );
$EXTRA_HTML='';
if(is_single()){$EXTRA_HTML='INSERT HTML HERE';}
    echo $EXTRA_HTML.$content;
}
```

I cant get my head around it. What should I put and WHERE? The updates just make it all go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure any solution you make up will not be overwritten on post and themes update, the best way around is creating a [Child Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) and adding the piece of HTML you want on its proper place. Probably on a loop template or single.php depending on how the base theme is structured.

This way, even if Wordpress or the Core Theme he's using is updated, you'll have your solution online as your Child Theme will not be replaced.

Another solution for this would be using a theme and make sure it's always online by making two simple adjustments on your WP setup:

1. On wp-content folder create a new folder called **mu-plugins** and drop your custom made plugin in there. **mu-plugins** stands for [Must Use Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) and plugins on this folder will always be enabled and can't be turn off unless you delete it from the server folder.
2. Make sure the user can't edit theme and plugin files by dropping `define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', true );` line on **wp-config.php**.

Both solutions will help you achieve this customization without a regular user being able to break it by simple button clicking around. If this can still be an issue, you can also hide any admin settings that can cause trouble in the future. I use [Adminimize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/) quite often with the solutions above to make sure any user will not click and break stuff around.

Comment: Thank you. Worked exactly as you mentioned and results where exactly as expected. I hug you, sir :)